# How does one start a non-login shell from a login shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sudo

I have a script that is designed to set up my system after a fresh install of the operating system.  Most of what it does requires superuser permissions, but some commands create, under the home directory, files, such as a lock file, to which the owner of said home directory must have write permission.  To avoid files for the superuser being created under my own home directory rather than `/root`, I require the script to be run with `sudo -i` and use `sudo -iu "$SUDO_USER"` to execute commands as me.

This works quite well most of the time, but I now need to execute a command as if I had run it with `sudo`, **NOT** `sudo -i`.  How should I do this?

A bad solution would be something like the following:

```
sudo -iu "$SUDO_USER" << LF
sudo [command]
LF
```

The problem with the above is that `sudo [command]` may prompt for a password, and this script must be non-interactive.

Comment: You want to edit sudo so it doesn't ask for permissions, maybe just for those commands & that user? `sudoedit`, but don't break your security

Comment: @Xen2050 That could work.  I could have the script make a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`, execute `sudo [command]` as me with `sudo -iu "$SUDO_USER"`, exit back into the script, and then remove the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Xen2050 suggested, I temporarily gave myself permission to execute the command as the superuser without authenticating.

I do this by adding a file under the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory with the `NOPASSWD` directive.  To be safe, I use `visudo`, so I have to use an ed script in a here-doc instead of a here-doc directly.  After running the command, I delete the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

EDITOR=ed visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/[file] << LF
a
$SUDO_USER $(hostname) = NOPASSWD: [command]
.
wq
LF
sudo -iu "$SUDO_USER" bash << LF
sudo [command]
LF
rm /etc/sudoers.d/[file]
```

Note that `[command]` in the ed script must include the command's full path.  I named `[file]` after the command.  In my case, I was running the installer for TeX Live, `install-tl`, so I chose that as the file's name.